# Flutter: Status bar pull down event

Tags: android, flutter, android-statusbar

Is there some kind of event that is triggered when a hidden status bar is pulled down in a Flutter app? I have to change a padding in my app when the Android status bar (initially hidden) gets pulled down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe wrap in GestureDetector widget and use onVerticalDragDown?
docs: [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html)

Comment: Thanks for the idea, that works so far. However, the solution is not perfect, because there is a small delay. I do not mark the answer as answered for now and wait whether someone has another idea.

Comment: Have you got the answer related to this?  as i have multiple situations where vertical dragdown is used so it might effect this, have you find any other solution ?